# I have maps in formats I do not understand (cpg, drf, prj, sbn, sbx, shp, xml, shx). How to change the colors?

Tags: maps

I have received some maps which are stored in zip archives. On those maps some regions are plotted, and they are marked with different colors. Each zip archive has different files in it, namely cpg, drf, prj, sbn, sbx, shp, xml, shx. I have tried to search on the internet, but it is difficult, since most articles assume that you have some basic knowledge about shapes and the topic in general.

I have no idea how this works, however, I am only interested in changing the color of different regions (e.g. blue, red, yellow). Could you please help me with the following two questions:

- How can I view the map and save it in, say JPG or PNG? Which program should I use?
- How to change a color of a region (which file and which program to use)?

Thank you!